# Como salvar os dados de uma view que está dentro de uma view em Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Eu renderizei uma view dentro de outra, pois o meu cadastro está com 3 tabelas dentro de um CRUD.

o form está na view customer.

E renderizei o custom_address desta maneria,

Obs.: ele salvará somente o endereço do cliente.

```
<%= form.fields_for :customer_addresses, @customer.customer_addresses.build do |customer_address_fields| %>
  <%= render 'customer_address_fields', customer_address_fields: customer_address_fields %>
<% end %>
```

Porém, quando eu salvo o customer, ele não está salvando o customer, queria uma ajuda nisso.

```
def customer_address_params
  params.permit(:address_type_id, :primary_address, :country, :zip_code, :street, :number, :complement, :district, :city, :state)
end
```

Porém não está vindo nenhum valor nas variáveis.

Answer (score 2):

Se o seu código referente ao `StrongParameters` (parâmetros permitidos) está apenas como você colocou acima, é preciso alterar para pegar os parametros a partir de `custumer`. Provavelmente, se você olhar o seu log server `rails s`, está vindo algo como

```
params = {person = {'name'=>'Costumer X', 
'costumer_address' => { 'address_type_id'=>1, 'zip_code'=>'01310100', 
'street'=>'Avenida Paulista'....}
```

Então, para pegar tantos os parâmetros do `costumer`, quando os do `costumer_address`, você deve permitir mais ou menos assim:

```
params.require(:costumer).permit(:name, 
  :other_costumer_params,
  { costumer_addresses_attributes: [:address_type_id, :primary_address, 
  :country, :zip_code, :street, :number, :complement,
  :district, :city, :state]})
```